# weird pcap packet length

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap

I am working with pcap in C and comparing the lengths of EAPOL handshakes with those get in wireshark, and the EAPOL packets captured with pcap are longer. The strange thing is that the added length is variable, some days it adds a header of 26 bytes and a footer of 4, making a 185 bytes packet (instead of the 155 byte in wireshark for the first message of the handshake). Some days it adds a 18 byte header with no footer, making a 173 byte packet. When it captures a packet of a certain length, it keeps that format for the whole day and the next day it switches to the other one. 
I have read this [Libpcap File Format](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) but the lengths of those headers don't fill the gap, and wireshark doesn't show Radiotap Headers so I guess I don't have any. The captured packet comes always between the same devices and wireshark returns always the same length. 
Anyone knows what is going on here? Thanks in advance guys!

As requested, I add some examples of the packets captured. For the sake of clarity I will paste only the first message of the handshake, and only for the 185 byte case, as it is the length I get today:

As captured by pcap (185 bytes). Extra bytes in **bold**:

**`00 00 1a 00 2f 48 00 00 f3 7c 7b 00 00 00 00 00 10 02 85 09 a0 00 db 01 00 00`**`88 02 3a 01 85 74 13 51 b4 a8 d8 b7 b8 17 92 81 d8 b7 b8 17 92 81 00 00 00 00 aa aa 03 00 00 00 88 8e 02 03 00 75 02 00 8a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 ed 35 bb b6 7d d9 0a 43 ba aa 09 23 f1 f6 6e c9 25 f3 13 c3 91 1c cd ae f5 47 98 0e 6b 15 7a fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 dd 14 00 0f ac 04 c2 8c 80 68 37 d8 87 fa 37 ab bd 07 1f c3 96 ee`**`cb f9 0b 91`**

The EAPOL packet as shown in Wireshark (155 bytes):

`88 02 3a 01 85 74 13 51 b4 a8 d8 b7 b8 17 92 81 d8 b7 b8 17 92 81 00 00 00 00 aa aa 03 00 00 00 88 8e 02 03 00 75 02 00 8a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 ed 35 bb b6 7d d9 0a 43 ba aa 09 23 f1 f6 6e c9 25 f3 13 c3 91 1c cd ae f5 47 98 0e 6b 15 7a fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 dd 14 00 0f ac 04 c2 8c 80 68 37 d8 87 fa 37 ab bd 07 1f c3 96 ee`

Comment: Maybe you could post some capture files somewhere (cloudshark, dropbox, pastebin, ...) so others could take a look.